# Producing Integers

Tags: number-sequence

Came up with the idea for this one while I was scratching my head over another "what comes next" puzzle here on Puzzling.SE

> I wrote a small application which takes an integer and returns another integer.
>
> Sometimes the application finds multiple integers to return, so it always returns the smallest one it finds.
>
> Starting with '3' (seemed like a good number to start with), I used each integer that was returned as the next input, until I found the perfect place to stop!
>
> **3, 9, 5,  4, 2, 6, 7, 13, 110, 174, 155, ?**

**What was the number I stopped on and why is it the perfect place to stop?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

314

The program finds what position the input string is in pi. You started on 3 because it is the first digit in pi. 3 is in the 9th position (excluding the first one), 9 is in the 5th position, 5 is in the 4th position, etc.

314 is the perfect place to stop because it is visually similar to a very common approximation of pi, 3.14.

As a side note, I'm embarrassed to admit that I found [the sequence](https://oeis.org/) on the [Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/); you might want to check that in the future ;)

Comment: Heck! I wouldn't have imagined it would've appeared there, good find all the same!

Comment: @Rolodophone Further evidence: "Producing Integers" is abbreviated P.I.